# Replace with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace a text like "New York (1224)" with only "New York".

I have `var name = $(this).text().replace(' ()','')`

That replaces "New York ()" with only "New York". But how can I make it with a regex that handles digits like in the example?

Comment: Maybe `$(this).text().replace(/ \(\d+\)/g, '')`?

Comment: Please clarify: 1) do you expect multiple values to be removed in  1 string? 2) is the value you need to remove always at the end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove *anything* and wrapping parentheses

If you're **not** specifically interested in ***digits***

```
\s*\([^)]*\)\s*$
```

will help you target anything enclosed in parentheses `()` and trim some spaces resulting in removing the highlighted portions like:

https://regex101.com/r/GyOc5X/1

[image: Regex remove parentheses and it's content]

### Remove *numbers* and wrapping parentheses

otherwise, if you're strictly only interested in **numbers wrapped in parentheses** - and some whitespace trimming:

```
\s*\(\d+\)\s*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/GyOc5X/2

[image]

```
var name = $(this).text().replace(/\s*\(\d+\)\s*$/, "");   //New York
```

<sub>P.S:</sub>

- If you want to also target the specific `What ()` case from above than just replace `\d+` with `\d*` like:
  `\s*\(\d*\)\s*$`
- If you're flexible about *End-of-string* (meaning you have more text after the match) than simply remove the last `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex

```
var name = $(this).text().replace(/\s\(\d+\)/,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var name = $(this).text().replace( /\(\d+\)$/,'')
```

This will replace any (number+) at the end of the string, but will not do it if it's anywhere else in the string. You can view http://regexr.com/3fqld to see what all it would replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(this).text().replace(/\s+\(\d+\)/g, "")
```

```js
var str = "New York (1224)";
var replacement = str.replace(/\(\d+\)/g, "");
console.log(replacement);
```